# Building geojson coordinate grid in JS

Tags: javascript, coordinates, geojson

I’m trying to build a coordinate grid using geojson format. My JS knowledge is a little basic so I’m struggling on how to build the grid not just in the x direction but the y direction, so I end up with a square grid not just a x-axis line.

This is my code:

```
var yStart = -90; // Start coodinatate on y-axis
var xEnd = 180; // End point on x-axis
var yEnd = 90; // End point on y-axis
var gridSize = 10; // Size of the grid increments

geojson['type'] = 'FeatureCollection';
geojson['features'] = [];

for (let i = xStart; i <= xEnd; i += gridSize) {
    var newFeature = {
        "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
    },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": (i, i)
        }
    }
    geojson['features'].push(newFeature);
}
console.log(geojson);
```

How do I turn this from an x-axis incrementing loop to both x and y axis so it builds a grid not just a line of coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is boiling down to the fact that enclosing your coordinate values in parenthesis `()` is *materially different* that what is intended or expected as part of GeoJSON. Take the following example - in this instance, what you believe to be the x, y point `1, 2` evaluates to simply `2` in JavaScript:

```js
console.log((1, 2))
```

It's clear from the [documentation on GeoJSON FeatureCollection](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-1.5) that the values for "coordinates" of a Polygon are expressed as an Array of Arrays (both enclosed in square brackets):

```
var newFeature = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[i, i]]
  }
}
geojson['features'].push(newFeature);
```

It's not clear where you got the guidance to the contrary to use parenthesis to enclose your coordinate values. It's also not clear how a single point is meant to create a polygon in this instance, but I can't knock it if it meets your requirements.